# Next.js 13.4 fetching not working in production

Tags: next.js, fetch, prisma, production, next.js13

The problem is, everything is working perfectly in development, but if I start in production, create a row in prisma in production, and when I try to retrieve the row that I created while I was in production, he retrieved only the old ones before the npm run build. What is the problem, and how to solve it?

Frontend:

```
 const fetchPdfFiles = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("before fetching");
      const response = await fetch("/api/pdf-files");
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();

        setPdfFiles(data);
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to fetch PDF files");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
```

Backend:
/api/pdf-files

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  console.log("Before try catch block");
  try {
    const pdfFiles = await prisma?.pdfFile.findMany();


    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(pdfFiles));
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error);
    return new NextResponse(error);
  }
}
```

I also tried in frontend to do  { cache: "no-store" }, { cache: "no-cache" }. But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [Full Route Cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#1-react-rendering-on-the-server)

> Next.js automatically renders and caches routes at build time. This is
> an optimization that allows you to serve the cached route instead of
> rendering on the server for every request, resulting in faster page
> loads.

When you build your app, next.js looks at the routes and if they are static, it caches them. During the build time, next.js fetches from database and renders that HTML, save it in `next` folder. next time when you visit the same route, `next.js` will serve the cached HTML. if you delete, update or create a new entry, this cached HTML will be served.

when you build your app you will see a little circle next to static routes and lambda for dynamic routes:
[image]

By default, all routes are static in next.js. if you do any of followings in your page, that page will be marked as dynamic page

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
export const revalidate = 0
```

this will cache entire route. you can also use

```
 import {revalidatePath} from "next/cache"
```

after you mutate the data, call `revalidatePath("/path")`. This will rerender the page with new data and replace the old cached file with the new HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the self APIs of NextJS in server side.
It's possible to call in client side.
For example:

self APIs can't be called in server components in app route version.
self APIs can't be called in getServerSideProps method in page route version.

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the client side fetch function in a `useEffect()` and call it from there.

Answer (score -1):

The request is being cached at build time.

Add this line below so it won't be cached:

```
export const revalidate = 0
```